# What does SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN do

Tags: android, android-view

In simple words what does the below statement do when added to activity?

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 6):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)

This is the same as setting the system bars to be translucent (content will continue under the status and navigation bars), except that it won't draw the status and nav bar for you.